# Display mysql data in a new div per row returned

Tags: php, mysql

I have created the following however it is not displaying the data correctly, I wish for a new div per line of data from the database.

```
<?php
include_once '\inc\header.php';

$db_server = mysql_connect($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password);

if (!$db_server) die("Unable to connect to MySQL: ". mysql_error());

mysql_select_db($db_database)
or die ("Unable to select database: " . mysql_error());

$query = "select * from deal";
$result = mysql_query($query);

if (!$result) die ("Database access failed: " . mysql_error());
?>

<body class="metrouicss" onload="prettyPrint()" style="zoom: 1;">
<div id="container">

<?php
foreach($result as $tile)
    {?>
        <div class="item tile double bg-color-red">
                <?php echo $tile['name']?>
        </div>
    <?php }?>
</div>


<?php 
mysql_close ($db_server);
?>
```

`

Comment: Where are you fetching the results?

Comment: Do `var_dump($result)` and see, if result holds multiple values

Comment: Change your foreach to, while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { .. $row['name'].. }

Comment: Add this line below if(!$result)  :  $result = mysql_fetch_array($result);

Comment: Thanks everyone for you help, I see how to do it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    <?php
include_once '\inc\header.php';

$db_server = mysql_connect($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password);

if (!$db_server) die("Unable to connect to MySQL: ". mysql_error());

mysql_select_db($db_database)
or die ("Unable to select database: " . mysql_error());

$query = "select * from deal";
$result = mysql_query($query);

if (!$result) die ("Database access failed: " . mysql_error());
?>

<body class="metrouicss" onload="prettyPrint()" style="zoom: 1;">
<div id="container">

 <?php
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {?>
        <div class="item tile double bg-color-red">
                <?php echo $row['name']?>
        </div>
    <?php }?>
</div>


<?php 
mysql_close ($db_server);
?>
```

Try it!

Comment: Don't cut&paste an entire code block, and change only one line, without indicating at all what you did, or where. Your change is correct, but since it's utterly buried in the code, it's useless.

Answer (score 0):

`mysql_query()` returns a result handle. It is NOT an array you can loop on, which means

```
foreach($result as $tile) {
```

is wrong. It should be

```
while ($tile = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
```

instead.

Answer (score 0):

Add `$result = mysql_fetch_array($result);`
below `if (!$result) die ("Database access failed: " . mysql_error());`

Mysql query returns a mysql resource object. You need some additional functions like `mysql_fetch_array` to do something with it.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider moving over to `MySQLi` or `PDO`. Anyway, another way (using your mysql) would be to use `$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)` within a while loop condition.

```
<?php
include_once '\inc\header.php';

$db_server = mysql_connect($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password);

if (!$db_server) die("Unable to connect to MySQL: ". mysql_error());

mysql_select_db($db_database)
or die ("Unable to select database: " . mysql_error());

$query = "select * from deal";
$result = mysql_query($query);

if (!$result) die ("Database access failed: " . mysql_error());
?>

<body class="metrouicss" onload="prettyPrint()" style="zoom: 1;">
<div id="container">

<?php
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {?>
        <div class="item tile double bg-color-red">
                <?php echo $row['name']?>
        </div>
    <?php }?>
</div>


<?php 
mysql_close ($db_server);
?>
```